# YouTube Iframe API Unable to post message to http. Recipient has origin https

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, safari, youtube-iframe-api

Using the YouTube Iframe API I get the following error in Safary 9.1, OS X Yosemite.

> Unable to post message to http://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin https://www.youtube.com

The page does work in other browsers (e.g. Firefox, Chrome etc). Also, it turns out that it's broken only on one specific machine. It does work on another machine running same OS and browser.

I have no idea where to start debugging this.

The iframe HTML code generated looks like this:

```
<iframe id="myVideo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player" width="200" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/?html5=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=0&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=1&amp;playsinline=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com"></iframe>
```

The JavaScript code is this:

```
...
vid_frame = new YT.Player(id, {
    height: '200',
    width: '200',
    videoId: id,
    playerVars: {
       html5: 1,
       showinfo: showVideoInfo,
       autoplay: 0,
       rel: showRelatedVideos,
       controls: showPlayerControls,
       playsinline: 1
    },
    events: {
        onReady: onPlayerReady
    }
});
```

I feel like there is a browser setting that blocks the communication between the website and YouTube API but the error simply says that `https://www.youtube.com` is trying to send something to `http://www.youtube.com` (instead of `https`).

I tried to manually change the `http` into `https` (in the iframe urls), but then I get warnings saying:

> `Untrusted origin: http://example.com`

(because the main website is server over `http`)

How to fix this?

I did see this related question: [Unable to post message to http://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin https://www.youtube.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20063255/1420197)

Where to start debugging this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not load the YouTube Iframe API using the `<script src='path/to/iframe_api'></script>` tag, but use the way they recommend in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements):

This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

In fact, create the `script` tag from the JavaScript side, don't put it directly in the HTML (e.g. `<script src="..."></script>`).

Comment: Interestingly, this did fix my problem. Not sure why. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `<embed>` URL to `https://`:

```
<iframe id="myVideo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" title="YouTube video player"
        width="200" height="200" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?html5=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=0&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=1&amp;playsinline=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com"></iframe>
<!----------------------------------------^
```

The reason being, loading `https://` content over `http://` is okay, but no the other way round. And finally, if that doesn't work, you can any time use CloudFlare's free SSL proxy.

Comment: I did mention that *I tried to manually change the http into https (in the iframe urls), but then I get warnings saying: Untrusted origin: http://example.com*

Comment: @IonicăBizău Is there a place where we can see the live code and the error?